# ParseExact - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: powershell, datetime, date-parsing

I'm trying to convert string variable to datetime format:

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact($tempdate, 'dd.MM.yyyy', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture).ToString('yyMMdd')
```

`$tempdate` contains date in format `dd.MM.yyyy` which was obtained from an Excel file.

Unfortunately I'm getting error message:

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a
valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ [DateTime]::ParseExact($tempdate, 'dd.MM.yyyy', [CultureInfo]::Invaria ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

It works fine when I put 'clean date' instead of variable.

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('13.03.2017', 'dd.MM.yyyy', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture).ToString('yyMMdd')
```

What is wrong with this variable or how can I convert it to datetime in other way?

Comment: [What's the issue with this ParseExact code in PowerShell](//stackoverflow.com/q/17940647)

Comment: What is the type and value of `$tempdate`?

Comment: Can't help you unless we know more about `$tempdate`. Does the linked question from wOxxOm help? What is the current type?  `$tempdate.GetType().Fullname`. Are there any leading or trailing spaces? `"'$tempdate'"`

Comment: @Matt - thank you for your answer. There was escape character in the end of the string(next line). I removed it and it works. FYI - $tempdate is a string and contains 13.03.2017. Of course I need to convert multiple variables in this way. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works fine when I put 'clean date' instead of variable.

That tells me something is wrong with your `$tempdate` first and foremost it should be a string but you could have an issue with leading or trailing whitespace. Consider the following.

```
PS C:\Users\Bagel> [DateTime]::ParseExact(' 13.03.2017 ', 'dd.MM.yyyy',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ [DateTime]::ParseExact(' 13.03.2017 ', 'dd.MM.yyyy',[CultureInfo]::In ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

So, as we have discovered in comments, this appears to be your problem. A simple `.trim()` should handle this for you assuming you do not have control over how `$tempdate` is populated (If you do you should fix the issue there first).

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact(' 13.03.2017 '.Trim(), 'dd.MM.yyyy',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```