# Convert Expiration date in Int32 to date in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working on F5 SSL  certificate's and i am getting Below output on Expiry date and Expirationstring

expirationDate              : 1531094399

expirationString            : Jul  8 23:59:59 2018 GMT

Question 1:  How to i convert Expiration date which is int 32 to date  and compare with current date ?

Question 2 :  How can i compare ExpirationString with my current time/date ? . I want to generate mail when certificate is going to after 30 days .

[Expirationdate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0cgk.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Iwu3.png)

I am working in Powershell  so request the same code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Method gives you `DateTimeOffset` where, among other, you have `datetime` properties DateTime and LocalDateTime.

`[System.DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeSeconds(1531094399)`

2. This manages to parse short month name, time zone and one or two day digits:

`[datetime]::ParseExact('Jul 8 23:59:59 2018 GMT','MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy Z',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)`

Comment: :Little help . I am Getting this error when i store  Expiration string in Variable .

$expirationString=$certificate.expirationString.Trim()     #making sure there are no spaces
H:\> $expirationString
Jul  8 23:59:59 2018 GMT
 H:\> $expirationString.GetType().fullname
System.String

$expirationString1=([datetime]::ParseExact($expirationString,'MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy Z',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture))

Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a 
valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1

Comment: @TarunGupta It seems fine and works for me on machines with different language settings. Does the example from my answer work?

Comment: Hi @AdamL 
  yes it works , when i put the string directly 

//Works 
[datetime]::ParseExact('Jul 8 23:59:59 2018 GMT','MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy Z',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)

//does not work 
$expirationString=$certificate.expirationString.Trim()
$expirationString1=([datetime]::ParseExact($expirationString,'MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy Z',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture))

Comment: This is the same issue i am having but not able to resolve .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784919/parseexact-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime ..

It works fine when I put ' date' instead of variable.

Comment: There must be something goin on with $certificate.expirationString Are you sure it is a string in correct format?

Comment: Hi @AdamL: 
  yes ,  all i am doing is storing in a variable . Just  to  make sure there are no spaces/funny characters , i am doing   $expirationString=$certificate.expirationString.Trim()    as well .   

$expirationString.GetType().fullname  System.String

Comment: Then I don't know. You'd have to send code that can replicate the problem.