# Extracting date from a file name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have written a PowerShell script to extract the date from filenames and delete based on that.

Sample file name: TBTT_UAT_01012021_000019.csv

Code to extract date :

```
  $fileDateText = ($filename -split '_')[4]
  $fileDate = [System.DateTime]::ParseExact($fileDateText, "dd/MM/yyyy", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

But I am getting the following error when I run the script, as it recognizes the date before CSV:

String '000019.csv' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.: FormatException

Can someone advise, please?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure the date you are parsing is the element 4 of the splitted string and not the 2nd or 3rd?

Comment: Yes it is the element 3 , which works fine on powershell 5 , but I need to run on PowerShell 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be looking at the wrong array element returning from your split.  Also the string you are giving in the overloads for `.ParseExact()` may be off.  This seemed to work in my tests:

```
$fileDate = ("TBTT_UAT_01012021_000019.csv" -split '_')[2]
[DateTime]::ParseExact($fileDate, "ddMMyyyy", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Returned: `Friday, January 1, 2021 12:00:00 AM`

If you want to get more granular about the time we'll have to cut up the string file name differently.

Comment: Thanks Steve , it works for me on PowerShell version 5 , but on PowerShell 7 , I am getting the same error.

Comment: I am new to powershell 7 , Do you know if there is a way to to do the same in PoweShell 7 ?

Comment: Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String '01012021' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

String 01012021 is 1st January 2021 , it is being recognized on powershell 5 , but not on 7.

Comment: I see that you've since fixed the issue. I believe the problem was you may not have changed the string format provider, as had been outlined in the answer.  It was argument/overload #2: "ddMMyyyy". If you are comfortable please accept the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($filename -match '(?<Timestamp>\d{8})') {
    [DateTime]::ParseExact($Matches.Timestamp, 'ddMMyyyy', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
}
```

I gravitate toward regexes with named extraction groups rather than doing string manipulation.  The syntax is a bit more fiddly, but the resulting script ends up being more resilient.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed by changing from:

```
[System.DateTime]::ParseExact($fileDateText, "dd/MM/yyyy", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

to

```
$fileDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact("$fileDateText", 'ddMMyyyy',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784919/parseexact-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime